# How to log configuration changes in a sensible way?

Tags: 8, configuration, log-messages

In order to log simple configuration changes like a site-name change, contributed modules like `contrib_log` work fine.

It just diffs the changes files in active configuration and logs it.

But when you change a field definition or delete(!) a content type, the logs are not so descriptive and we get a whole lot of .yml files changes log, not really describing what happened. We only see all the .yml files changed and their diff, and that doesn't have much value. I mean there is naturally no log line saying : "New field  added." or "Language French removed".

I understand why it is like that, but I'm looking for a way to add value to these logs.

I've looked into `Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigEvents` and trying to figure out if there is a way to know when we are changing a content type or a language for example and log this change in a sensible way, without logging a set of unreadable `.yml` file diffs?

Thank you

Comment: To log on a higher level you could use CRUD events for non simple configuration items (config entities) being created, updated or deleted, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/group/entity_crud/8.7.x

Comment: Yeah I've been playing around with `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeEvents` and `Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionEvents`, trying to achieve it without the entity hooks, thanks